# Why content manager is taking so much heap size?

Tags: c#, mono, garbage-collection, xna, monogame

Application is writed in C# with MonoGame API.
These app is designed for android, but i decided to optimize it a little so I port it for windows to get it working with CLRProfiler, and I found that Heap is in 77% Microsoft.Xna.Framework.Content.ContentManager->System.Byte[]. Is there any way to avoid GC collection in my app? Here is a part from it that has the problem:

```
using Microsoft.Xna.Framework;
using Microsoft.Xna.Framework.Graphics;
using Microsoft.Xna.Framework.Input;

namespace Game1
{
    public struct FPS_counter
    {
        float fps_from;
        int fps;
        public int fps_toshow;
        public float in_Secs;

        public void add_frame()
        {
            fps_from += in_Secs;  //(float)gameTime.ElapsedGameTime.TotalSeconds;
            if (fps_from > 1)
            {
                fps_toshow = fps;
                fps = 0;
                fps_from = 0;
            }
            fps++;
        }
    }

    public struct numbers
    {

        public Texture2D[] texture;
        public int num1, num2;
        public Vector2 pos1, pos2, origin;
        public int number;

        public void update()
        {

            num1 = 0;
            num2 = 0;
            int nuu = number;
            if (nuu > 10)
            {
                for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
                {
                    if (number >= (i * 10))
                    {
                        num1 = i;
                    }
                    else break;
                }
            }
            nuu -= num1 * 10;
            for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
            {
                if (nuu >= i)
                {
                    num2 = i;
                }
                else break;
            }

        }
        public void draw()
        {
            if (number > 9) Game1.spriteBatch.Draw(texture[num1], pos1, origin: origin);
            Game1.spriteBatch.Draw(texture[num2], pos2, origin: origin);
        }
    }

    public class Game1 : Game
    {
        GraphicsDeviceManager graphics;
        public static SpriteBatch spriteBatch;
        FPS_counter counter;
        numbers Numb;

        public Game1()
        {
            graphics = new GraphicsDeviceManager(this);
            Content.RootDirectory = "Content";
            counter = new FPS_counter();
            Numb = new numbers();
        }

        protected override void Initialize()
        {
            base.Initialize();
        }

        protected override void LoadContent()
        {
            spriteBatch = new SpriteBatch(GraphicsDevice);
            Numb.texture = new Texture2D[10];
            for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
            {
                Numb.texture[i] = Content.Load<Texture2D>(("" + i));
            }
            Numb.num1 = 0;
            Numb.num2 = 0;
            Numb.number = 22;
            Numb.pos1 = new Vector2(250, 50);
            Numb.pos2 = new Vector2(270, 50);
            Numb.origin = new Vector2(10, 10);

        }

        protected override void UnloadContent()
        {
        }

        protected override void Update(GameTime gameTime)
        {
            if (GamePad.GetState(PlayerIndex.One).Buttons.Back == ButtonState.Pressed || Keyboard.GetState().IsKeyDown(Keys.Escape))
                Exit();

            base.Update(gameTime);
        }

        protected override void Draw(GameTime gameTime)
        {
            GraphicsDevice.Clear(Color.CornflowerBlue);

            spriteBatch.Begin();
            counter.in_Secs = (float)gameTime.ElapsedGameTime.TotalSeconds;
            counter.add_frame();
            Numb.number = counter.fps_toshow;
            Numb.update();
            Numb.draw();
            spriteBatch.End();

            base.Draw(gameTime);
        }
    }
}
```

Sorry for bad English, I am from Poland.

Comment: Considering that what content manager deals with, i.e. assets, it is not surprising that it takes up a large percentage of heap space. That's to be expected. Is there a reason you believe this is a problem in your case?

Comment: Gc collection is lagging my game every 1,5 min, so yes.

Comment: I even try these: MONO_GC_PARAMS=nursery-size=32m
MONO_GC_PARAMS=soft-heap-limit=128m but then dalvikvm gc concurrent is doing the same

Comment: Or if there is any option to avoid GC, I wil try.

Answer (score 1):

In short, **You may be out of luck**.

But, there are things you can try.

As with every graphical program, stored assets can be overwhelming to the heap. So the best way to increase performance is to **only load what you need from the content manager**. Considering your program is lagging at garbage collection, you are, hopefully, loading more than you need into your heap without freeing it when you are finished with the asset. So when GC time comes around, it has to purge the 77% of the heap taken up, and the reallocate it as your code requests that memory.

*So how should you fix it?*

You probably need to write a memory manager. Keep a static reference to your content manager, but have methods to request assets to be loaded into your heap. This should hopefully cut out any of the extra heap use, but you should also include logic to clean, or replace, these assets from your heap when you are finished with them. **You don't want to avoid garbage collection, but optimize it.** I would be weary of anytime you call a `new` object creation as you may be able to store previously unchanged assets(textures, graphics, data...) in your memory manager. This can avoid unnecessary heap filling and prevent a burden on your garbage collection.

Memory management with graphical programs can be tricky, but I hope this helps put you in the correct direction.